# ValueError: X.shape[1] = 96 should be equal to 2, the number of features at training time

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification

I am following the tutorial here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_multilabel.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-miscellaneous-plot-multilabel-py.

I have texts that I want to classify, so I encoded them. On the lines

```
classif = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel = 'linear'))
classif.fit(X, Y)
```

my `X` is (188, 96) and my `Y` is (188, 2).

When I try to run `clf.predict(test)`, even though `test` is (56, 96), I get the error `ValueError: X.shape[1] = 96 should be equal to 2, the number of features at training time`. Where did the 2 features come from? My `Y` labels are 2D arrays, but my `X` has 96 columns.

Comment: What does 188 and 96 represents?

Comment: The X-data -- with no labels.